# Using props to set '&:hover' background-color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm wrapping Material UI's `Chip` component so that I can pass in values other than "primary" and "secondary" for the `colors` prop. I also want to maintain the hover effect if the chip is clickable so that the chip transitions to a different color when the cursor is over it. The colors are passed in as props, so it's easy enough to set the `backgroundColor` and `color`:

```
<Chip
  style={{
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
    color: props.color
  }}
/>
```

However, since I'd also like to pass in the hover color as a prop, I'd need to do something like this:

```
<Chip
  style={{
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
    color: props.color,
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: props.hoverBackgroundColor,
      color: props.hoverColor
    }
  }}
/>
```

However, the `&:hover` (as far as I know) can't be used inside of the `style` prop. Typically, the `&:hover` would be used inside of a styles object that is passed into `withStyles`, but I'm not able to access props from in there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating your own custom chip component. In order to be able to use props to control the styling, you can use the [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook). The `makeStyles` function returns a hook that can accept an object parameter for providing variables to your styles.

Here's a possible CustomChip implementaton:

```
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { emphasize } from "@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator";

const useChipStyles = makeStyles({
  chip: {
    color: ({ color }) => color,
    backgroundColor: ({ backgroundColor }) => backgroundColor,
    "&:hover, &:focus": {
      backgroundColor: ({ hoverBackgroundColor, backgroundColor }) =>
        hoverBackgroundColor
          ? hoverBackgroundColor
          : emphasize(backgroundColor, 0.08)
    },
    "&:active": {
      backgroundColor: ({ hoverBackgroundColor, backgroundColor }) =>
        emphasize(
          hoverBackgroundColor ? hoverBackgroundColor : backgroundColor,
          0.12
        )
    }
  }
});
const CustomChip = ({
  color,
  backgroundColor,
  hoverBackgroundColor,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const classes = useChipStyles({
    color,
    backgroundColor,
    hoverBackgroundColor
  });
  return <Chip className={classes.chip} {...rest} />;
};
export default CustomChip;
```

The styling approach (including the use of the `emphasize` function to generate the hover and active colors) is based on the approach used internally for [`Chip`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Chip/Chip.js#L90).

This can then be used like this:

```
      <CustomChip
        label="Custom Chip 1"
        color="green"
        backgroundColor="#ccf"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("clicked 1");
        }}
      />
      <CustomChip
        label="Custom Chip 2"
        color="#f0f"
        backgroundColor="#fcc"
        hoverBackgroundColor="#afa"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("clicked 2");
        }}
      />
```

Here's a CodeSandbox demonstrating this:

[image: Edit Chip color (forked)]

---

Here's a Material-UI v5 version of the example:

```
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { emphasize } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { shouldForwardProp } from "@material-ui/system";
function customShouldForwardProp(prop) {
  return (
    prop !== "color" &&
    prop !== "backgroundColor" &&
    prop !== "hoverBackgroundColor" &&
    shouldForwardProp(prop)
  );
}
const CustomChip = styled(Chip, { shouldForwardProp: customShouldForwardProp })(
  ({ color, backgroundColor, hoverBackgroundColor }) => ({
    color: color,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    "&:hover, &:focus": {
      backgroundColor: hoverBackgroundColor
        ? hoverBackgroundColor
        : emphasize(backgroundColor, 0.08)
    },
    "&:active": {
      backgroundColor: emphasize(
        hoverBackgroundColor ? hoverBackgroundColor : backgroundColor,
        0.12
      )
    }
  })
);

export default CustomChip;
```

[image: Edit Chip color]

Comment: This seems to work very well. Unfortunately, I'm on a version of React that doesn't support hooks. Hopefully we'll get there soon. In the mean time, I came up with a solution that uses an HOC to inject the styles using props into the component. Here's the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r41no67q0m?fontsize=14)

Comment: v4 of Material-UI will require hooks support, so in order to keep getting further Material-UI enhancements, you'll definitely want to get React upgraded. As long as you're already on React 16 and not some earlier version, it should be a pretty painless upgrade.

Comment: @RyanCogswell why do you call `shouldForwardProp` from the system package again? The example from the [docs](https://mui.com/system/styled/#custom-components) doesn't do it and it makes no difference to me when playing around in the codesandbox with or without the second `shouldForwardProp`.

Comment: @NearHuscarl I think I included it because in looking through the source it looked like when you specify a custom `shouldForwardProp` that it isn't additive to the default -- it replaces it. On the assumption that the default implementation has an impact in at least some scenarios, I included it, but I have not found a scenario where it seems to make a difference. The example in the docs does include part of the default implementation (checking for `sx`), but it isn't clear to me in what scenario that has an effect.

Comment: `it isn't additive to the default` That's why it's confusing to me, it looks like your code is the way to go based on the source since a custom `shouldForwardProp` [overrides the original one from the system completely](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-system/src/createStyled.js#L108-L110), it doesn't use `createChainedFunction` to merge multiple functions. There are probably some extra magic that I miss somewhere when reading the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In **Material UI v5**, you can use [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) to style pseudo-classes like `:hover`:

```
<Chip
  label="Chip"
  onClick={() => {}}
  sx={{
    ':hover': {
      bgcolor: 'red',
    },
  }}
/>
```

Another alternative is [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) if you want to create a reusable styled component:

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'hoverBgColor',
};
const StyledChip = styled(
  Chip,
  options,
)(({ hoverBgColor }) => ({
  ':hover': {
    backgroundColor: hoverBgColor,
  },
}));
```

```
<StyledChip label="Chip" onClick={() => {}} hoverBgColor="red" />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]